# problems with writing a file in C in a Linux environment

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to build a gym program for a project in college.
We're doing it in C in a Linux environment.
I do not have problems reading from the file, but when I try to update the file, if I print to file with '\n' at the end, it puts double enters between line.  And if I don't, it puts all the data in one line.

What should I do?

i.e. I've added an example of a function that reads from the file and one that updates it.

```
Employees** Init_Gym_emp(Employees** emp, int* num) {
    FILE* f = fopen("Gym Employees.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Failed opening the file. Exiting!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char c = '\0';
    while (fscanf(f, "%c", &c) == 1) {
        if (c == '\n') num[0]++;
    }
    if (num[0] > 0) num[0]++;
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    Employees* tmp = (Employees*)malloc(sizeof(Employees));
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    emp = (Employees**)malloc(sizeof(Employees*)*(num[0]));
    if (emp == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i = 0;
    tmp->first_name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 20);
    tmp->last_name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 20);
    tmp->user_name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 20);
    tmp->password = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 20);
    tmp->user_type = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 20);
    while (fscanf(f, "%20[^#]%*c%20[^#]%*c%ld%*c%20[^#]%*c%10[^#]%*c%20[^#]%*2c", tmp->first_name, tmp->last_name, &tmp->id, tmp->user_name, tmp->password, tmp->user_type) == 6) {
        emp[i] = (Employees*)malloc(sizeof(Employees));
        if (emp[i] == NULL) {
            printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        emp[i]->first_name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* (strlen(tmp->first_name) + 1));
        emp[i]->last_name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* (strlen(tmp->last_name) + 1));
        emp[i]->user_name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* (strlen(tmp->user_name) + 1));
        emp[i]->password = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* (strlen(tmp->password) + 1));
        emp[i]->user_type = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* (strlen(tmp->user_type) + 1));
        strcpy(emp[i]->first_name, tmp->first_name);
        strcpy(emp[i]->last_name, tmp->last_name);
        strcpy(emp[i]->user_name, tmp->user_name);
        strcpy(emp[i]->password, tmp->password);
        strcpy(emp[i]->user_type, tmp->user_type);
        emp[i]->id = tmp->id;
        i++;
    }
    free(tmp->first_name);
    free(tmp->last_name);
    free(tmp->user_name);
    free(tmp->password);
    free(tmp->user_type);
    free(tmp);
    fclose(f);
    return emp;
}


void update_Gym_emp(Employees** emp, int* num) {
    remove("Gym Employees.txt");
    FILE* f = fopen("Gym Employees.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Failed opening the file. Exiting!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num[0]; i++) {
        fprintf(f, "%s#%s#%ld#%s#%s#%s#", emp[i]->first_name, emp[i]->last_name, emp[i]->id, emp[i]->user_name, emp[i]->password, emp[i]->user_type);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Note: they say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc),

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It helps if people can compile the code and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why don't you declare `Employees`'s members as simple arrays of `char` if you are willing to handle only strings which are less than 20 characters?

Comment: First `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.  Second. if available you can use `strdup()` instead of `malloc()`/`strcpy()`.

Comment: the files have # between each data and in the end of the line

Comment: and has i know and did before %*2c work's fine

Comment: i don't have a problem with reading from the file i have problem with writing to it

Comment: I tried, it doesn’t help, it's worse with it, the software breaks when it's getting to the update function

Comment: When calling `malloc()` and family of functions, 1) do not cast the returned value.  it is already a `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  All the cast does is clutter the code and help to introduce errors when debugging and/or maintaining the code.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: always check the returned value from a call to `fseek()` to assure the operation was successful

Comment: there is no need to call `remove()` because the following call to `fopen()` will truncate the file

Comment: always check the returned value from a call to `remove()` to assure the operation was successful

Comment: You've gone all the trouble to check the result of malloc but used the memory right after a malloc call in your while loop.  Anyway, I'd create a macro that tests the pointer for null and does action if null.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way the code could be written.

Notice that the first function reads from a file and creates a 2D list of Employee records

Notice that the second function writes to that same file from the 2D list of Employee records

Notice the string lengths for the call to `fscanf()` are one less than the related input buffer size because when scanning a string, the function will always append a NUL byte to the string

Strongly suggest defining the Employee struct as follows rather than the way it is currently defined:

```
struct Employee
{
    char first_name[20];
    char last_name[20];
    long id;
    char user_name[20];
    char password[10];
    char user_type[20];
};
```

Now, the proposed code

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Employee
{
    char *first_name;
    char *last_name;
    long  id;
    char *user_name;
    char *password;
    char *user_type;
};

typedef struct Employee Employees;

// prototypes
void cleanup( Employees **emp );

Employees** Init_Gym_emp(Employees** emp, int* num)
{
    FILE* f = fopen("Gym Employees.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen for Gym Employees.txt for input failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    char buffer[1024]; // input work area

    // get count of records in file
    while ( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f) )
    {
        num[0]++;
    }

    // step back to beginning of file to read/parse each record
    if( fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET) )
    { // then fseek failed
         perror( "fseek to start of file failed" );
         fclose( f );
         exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fseek successful

    // allocate array of pointers large enough for all records in input file
    if( NULL == (*emp = malloc((size_t)num[0] * sizeof(Employees*) ) ) )
    {
        perror("malloc for array of pointers to Employee records failed");
        cleanup( emp );
        fclose( f );
        exit(1);
    }

    // clear all pointers to NULL, to make cleanup easier
    memset( *emp, '\0', (size_t)num[0] * sizeof( Employees* ));

    char first_name[20];
    char last_name[20];
    long id;
    char user_name[20];
    char password[10];
    char user_type[20];

    int i = 0;
    while( i < num[0] && fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), f ) )
    {
        if( 6 != sscanf(buffer,
                        "%19[^#]# %19[^#]# %ld# %19[^#]# %9[^#]# %19[^#]",
                        first_name,
                        last_name,
                        &id,
                        user_name,
                        password,
                        user_type) )
        { // then sscanf failed
            perror( "sscanf for fields of emp record failed" );
            cleanup( emp );
            fclose( f );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, sscanf successful

        // get room for one employee record
        if( NULL == (emp[i] = malloc(sizeof(Employees)) ) )
        {
            perror("malloc for new employee record failed");
            cleanup( emp );
            fclose( f );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, malloc successful

        (*emp)[i].first_name = strdup( first_name );
        (*emp)[i].last_name  = strdup( last_name );
        (*emp)[i].user_name  = strdup( user_name );
        (*emp)[i].password   = strdup( password );
        (*emp)[i].user_type  = strdup( user_type );
        (*emp)[i].id         = id;
        i++;
    } // end while


    fclose(f);
    return emp;
} // end function: Init_Gym_emp


void update_Gym_emp(Employees** emp, int* num)
{
    FILE* f = fopen("Gym Employees.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen for Gym Employees.txt for write failed");
        cleanup( emp );
        exit(1);
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    for (int i = 0; i < num[0]; i++)
    {
        fprintf(f, "%s#%s#%ld#%s#%s#%s#",
                (*emp)[i].first_name,
                (*emp)[i].last_name,
                (*emp)[i].id,
                (*emp)[i].user_name,
                (*emp)[i].password,
                (*emp)[i].user_type);
    }
    fclose(f);
} // end function: update_Gym_emp
```